# How can I associate any product icon with a VS Code Profile instead of just from the limited subset in v1.83?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Unable to select custom icon for profile

Tried to select one, but the available set of icons has limited number of options.
I was expecting to set some icon related Angular, for eg I can identify its a Angular Platform Profile, like some other case.

[image: Official Image for Feature]

Kudos for the latest Feature added in September 2023 update (Release 1.83.0) about Icons for profiles. But needed more in addition to that.

Comment: You could try asking the VS code team on there github page: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: I just asked the maintainers about this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/188972#issuecomment-1751413757. waiting for a reply.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the maintainers ([here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/188972#issuecomment-1751413757)) about why they don't allow picking from [the full list of product icons](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels), and one of the maintainers replied in agreement that the icon picker should be generalized. So I'm pretty sure the answer to this question is just to wait patiently for them to do that (or help implement that change). I'll update this answer post as things progress.